# I want to know how to deliver the value from rxjs to the subject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fgzw2i?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

```
export class myCalss {
  sub$: BehaviorSubject<number>;

  constructor() {
    this.sub$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  }

  test() {
    from([1,2,3,4]).subscribe(
      this.sub$.next,   // num => this.sub$.next(num)
      console.log
    )
  }
}
```

It's my code. There is an error in the code, but I don't know why. Please let me know if there is any problem in this code. Especially when the value is passed inside the subscribe function, I am curious about the part where you want to pass the passed value to the sub$. Normally, i write code as follows.

`num => this.sub$.next(num)`

But I found out that I can write it like this, too, isn't it?
`this.sub$.next`

Comment: Not clear what's the issue here... `next` is a method so the right syntax is `this.sub$.next(num)`

Comment: @lbsn ```this.sub$.next```So this syntax is wrong?

Comment: It's wrong if what you want is to call the `next` function and emit a value, which is obviously your intention in this case. It is not wrong in absolute terms, it's valid JS syntax but what you get with `this.sub$.next` is just a reference to the `next` property on your `BehaviourSubject` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in this case, because your `Subject` is of type `<number>`. If i remember correctly as of `rxjs 7` you can call `this.sub$.next()` without argument but `Subject` has to be of type `<void>`. The only usage it has are the cases where emitted value does not have any importance, what has importance is the fact that the value was emitted, even if it is `nothing`. As per [docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#void-subject), an example would be a reactive `timer`, I can't see the point anyways,  Why would you call it with empty argument, it's unclear to someone who has not seen the process of development. It causes problems when used in combination with `takeUntil`.  Also, this can fire compile error because of `strict mode`. It should be
like below, well not like you can do it other way if the type is `<number>`...

Anyways, you have set up a logic that emmits certain value, and that value should be treated somewhere in some way, but `next()` without argument is used when emitted value does not matter. Even if you could use it, it is inadequate in this case.

Use

```
test() {
   from([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe({
     next: (data) => {
       this.sub$.next(data);
     },
   });
 }
```

or just

```
  test() {
    from([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe((data) => {
      this.sub$.next(data);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I found out that I can write it like this, too, isn't it? this.sub$.next

Short answer: sadly, no. While this syntax is not wrong *per se*, you get an error because the scope of `this` gets lost if you use this "high order function" syntax.

Long answer:

The class `Subject` of the rxjs library uses the `this` keyword at some point, so passing the function as a parameter to the `subscribe` makes it to lose the right scope.
Consider this example:

```
class MockSubject {
  next(value) {
    console.log('A function not referring `this` ' + value);
  }
}
```

and here is an example of usage like you tried:

```
  mockSubject = new MockSubject;
  test() {
    from([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe(
      this.mockSubject.next, // num => this.sub$.next(num)
      console.log,
    );
  }
```

This example doesn't get that error you get because the method `next` of the class `MockSubject` doesn't refer to the `this` object. Of course, you can't know if a function in a class uses the `this` keyword, so my advice is to just avoid that syntax.

(the complete example in a stackblitz forked from yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-1jrzbf?file=index.ts)

And as a final tip, don't use the subscribe method with two callbacks since this way is deprecated - use the `PartialObserver` object instead like this:

```
{
   next: num => this.sub$.next(num), // num => this.sub$.next(num),
   error: console.log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
export class MyCalss {
  sub$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  number$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
    tap((num) => console.log),
    tap((num) => this.sub$.next)
  );

  test() {
    this.number$.subscribe();
  }
}
```